# Sorting an Array C#

Tags: c#, arrays, sorting

I am trying to sort an array before printing the coordinates to the console.  I tried to resort the Ships array based on the Y coordinate.  I need to reorder it so I can print them in order.  i tried Array.Sort(myArray) - fails, I tried converting to a list or dictionary but not sure that is the best way.  Any suggestions?

[Need to resort the Ships array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cZGH6.png)

Comment: What exactly do you mean by `Array.Sort(myArray)` fails? Is there an error message? Does the actual result differ from the expected result? If so, how? Please provide an example, preferrably with some actual code.

Comment: How many dimensions is the array? See here. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.sort(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: _"i tried Array.Sort(myArray) - fails"_ fails as a question. Always include full error details, expected and actual results etc.

Comment: Are the ships classes or anonymous objects?  Can you post your classes (if any).

Comment: Sorry, I thought the picture would sum it up.  When attempting to use Array.Sort(), I receive "failed to compare two elements in the array in the array" or when attempting via the orderby or orderbydescending it finds a null value and blows up.  I am updating a grid 10 x 10 (battleship board) based on what ship the user selects.  All I want to do is sort the array and I don't know how.  I can see what is occuring in the debugger (provided a screen shot) need index 1 to become index 0 because the Ycoordinate is smaller.

Comment: @Adam what picture? There's no picture here only a link. DON'T post pictures of the code, post the code itself. Pictures can't be compiled and debugged. A picture of an arrays contents says nothing by the way. Array.Sort isn't broken. Trying other containers to cover up a comparison bug won't fix the comparison bug. How will `Sort` or `OrderBy` know what to sort and how to compare items?

Answer (score 1):

Use the LINQ [OrderBy()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534966(v=vs.110).aspx) method. Assuming you want to sort by the YCoordinate of the last BoardPosition, and YCoordinate implements `IComparable` (e.g. is an `int`):

```
using System.Linq;

Ship[] ships;
Ship[] sorted = ships.OrderBy(s => s.BoardPositions.Last().YCoordinate).ToArray();
```

**Edit** The above code assumes that for every Ship in `Ship[] ships`, at least one entry in `BoardPositions` exists. If `BoardPositions` might be empty, use `LastOrDefault()` and the null-conditional operator `?.`.

```
Ship[] sorted = ships
    .OrderBy(ship => ship.BoardPositions.Any())
    .ThenBy(ship => ship.BoardPositions.LastOrDefault()?.YCoordinate)
    .ToArray();
```

Comment: received the following error:  "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"

Comment: @Adam You need to initialize the `ships` array somehow. How are you filling it in the original code?

Comment: it's private set only public get - I'm not allowed to change it.  It's an assignment of sorts.

Comment: I guess the problem is that BoardPositions might be empty, see my edit.

Answer (score 0):

In order for the Array.Sort(myArray) to do what you expect, the elements of myArray (im going to assume ships) need to be comparable. That is you need to specify how you want them compared (presumably Y coordinate).

The approach to this is either have the ship class implement the IComparable interface or to use [a different sort method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aw9s5t8f(v=vs.110).aspx) whereby you would separately define a comparer to use.

I can't give example code as there isn't anything to go off in your question.